# PHP appointment -> registers when it should not do it ..what am i missing?

Tags: php

So basically i wanted to make a medical appointment page and i wanted to not register the pacient if he/she wants to see the same doctor at the same date and the same hour with another pacient.
Here is my php code :

```
$con2 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cabinet');

$sql="SELECT data,ora,doctorul FROM programare";
  $res2=mysqli_query($con2,$sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
    $data2=$row['data'];
    $ora2=$row['ora'];
    $doctor2=$row['doctorul'];
  }

if (isset($_POST['programare'])) {
  $errors=array();
  $nume=$_POST['nume'];
  $data=$_POST['data'];
  $ora=$_POST['ora'];
  $tip=$_POST['tip'];
  $doctor=$_POST['doctor'];

if(!empty($nume) && !empty($data) && !empty($ora) && !empty($doctor)){
  if ($data == $data2 && $ora == $ora2 && $doctor == $doctor2) {
    array_push($errors,"Programare existenta la acea ora!");
  }else{
        $sql2="INSERT INTO programare(nume,data,ora,tipul,doctorul)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        mysqli_query($con2,$sql2);
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con2);
         if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql2)){
         echo "SQL error";
          } else {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss",$nume,$data,$ora,$tip,$doctor);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
        array_push($errors,"Programare inregistrata");
  }
}else{
      array_push($errors,"Introduceti toate datele!");
    }

}
```

So if i register pacient1 to doctor1 at date1 hour1 and after that i want to register pacient2 to doctor1 at date1 hour1 it works ..it doesn't register pacient2 but if i register pacient3 to doctor2 at date2 hour2 and after that i register pacient4 to doctor1 at date1 hour1 it works...and it shouldn't ...so what am i missing in my code ?

Here is the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="post">
                    <?php  include('erori.php');  ?>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputFocus">Nume</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input class="form-control" id="inputFocus" type="text" name="nume" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputFocus">Tip</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input class="form-control" id="inputFocus" type="text" name="tip" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputFocus">Data</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input class="form-control" id="datepicker2" type="text" name="data" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputFocus">Ora</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <input class="form-control" id="inputFocus" type="text" name="ora" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Doctor</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <select data-plugin-selectTwo class="form-control populate" name="doctor">
                        <option></option>
                         <?php 
                             $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cabinet');

                             $sql="SELECT user FROM users WHERE level='1'";
                             $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                                 echo "<option>".$row['user']."</option>";
                              }

                              ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group" id="btnform">
                         <button type="submit" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-primary" name="programare">Inregistrare</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: It scares me that medical systems that are potentially safety-critical are developed by novice engineers with no oversight. Hopefully, this is a toy project and will cause no harm

Comment: Your first SELECT should check if there is a row that matches the input fields, if there is, don't insert. Another option, you could use a composite key on those fields.

Comment: @EriksKlotins don't worry sir it's for a project for my school and ty for your answer.

Comment: @JonStirling am i not checking here :  if ($data == $data2 && $ora == $ora2 && $doctor == $doctor2) because i gave $data2 to $row['data'] / $ora2 to $row['ora'] and $doctor2 to $row['doctorul'] from my table where i have all the appointments and the $data,$ora,$doctor are taken from my inputs ..

Comment: @Trick.Andrei Because you have it in a loop and are looping around every row, those variables are only ever going to be of the _last_ row returned by the result set. Which isn't what you're wanting to do.

Comment: @JonStirling i changed the code based on what you said and it now works perfectly ^^ ty so much sir .. have a nice day.